# Connecting multiple audio crossovers

Tags: audio

If you feed the high-frequency output of a passive audio crossover to another passive crossover, will the crossovers interfere with each other poorly in some way and produce unexpected results, or will it 'just work'?

For instance, if i have a 2-way passive crossover that separates the input around 80hz. If i feed its high-frequency output into another crossover that splits into tweeter/midrange frequencies, is that reasonable? Or is this only feasible if using a single 3-way crossover.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will not work as planned. The second crossover loads down the first crossover. This has the effect of changing the frequency response and the impedance. In principle, you can design the first stage to accommodate the second stage knowing this arrangement at design time, but it's highly unorthodox and you would be re-inventing the the 3-way crossover with a weird cascaded architecture.

It might still be worth trying: from an engineering standpoint, it's a poor approach. But from an audio fidelity standpoint, where "how it actually sounds", only matters to the listener, it might be a successful build (even if your spectrum looks like trash).

Answer (score 2):

Passive filters are designed for certain signal source output series impedance and for certain load. Your 2nd filter is not a good load and it gets its input from a wrong kind of source. Get a  single input 3 output crossover filter which is designed properly for your actual speaker elements AND your speaker cabinet.

The cabinet affects much what's the right filter design, because the electric behaviour of the speaker is not independent from the acoustics. Maybe you cannot see any relation, but also the current intake of rotating electric machines depends on the mechanical load. Linear motion machines like speaker elements do the same.

Today high end speaker manufacturers have separate amps for the elements which allows low power filters which can be made as analog opamp circuits or DSP programs. The filter can be as complex as needed without dissipating the audio power between the amp and the speaker element.

Making such designs is far from trivial. To make it successfully by yourself you need electroacoustic detail data of the speaker elements (not available for cheap webshop stuff), acoustics & electronics engineering (including math) knowledge and a bunch of good acoustics and electronics measuring instruments.

As already said by others: Pleasant sound for certain purposes is different thing than accurate sound reproduction. I have put together for a band some vocal reinforcement speaker cabinets which were based on guesses with no proper design. But they created just the wanted bright and loud sound, no matter they were total rubbish as hi-fi equipment.